# Angular material input validation not working as expected

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-validation

I have an input field which gets validated on (keypress). However this is not happening. The only time it works is if I go to another input field or click away and return. This is my code for it.

```
  <mat-form-field>
    <input matInput placeholder="Network Address" name="network" [(ngModel)]="model.network" required (keypress)="validate($event)">
    <mat-hint>CIDR format, e.g. 192.168.65.0/25</mat-hint>
    <mat-error *ngFor="let error of errors_by_field['network']">{{error.message}}</mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>

  validate() {
    this.http.post<GetItemResult>('/api/branches', this.model).subscribe(data => {
        this.result = data;
        console.log(this.result);
        this.branch = data.item;
        this.errors_by_field = errors_by_field(data.errors);
        for (const [field, errors] of Object.entries(this.errors_by_field)) {
          if (field !== 'global') {
            this.form.form.controls[field].setErrors({server_error: true});
          }
        }
      },
      err => {
        this.submitting = false;
      });
  }
```

When I console log the ts code result, it prints out the result on every key press, its just not showing the  on the first time the input is touched. I have to click elsewhere and return for it to work

Comment: show your .ts code as well

Comment: please see edit in question

Answer (score 1):

Try with `(input)="validate($event)"`instead of `(keypress)`. I think `keypress` is executed only when the focus switch on another element.

If it's not a reactive form, you can also use `(ngModelChange)`.

Comment: tried it, still does the same thing, tried (keyup/down), (ngModalChange), (input), starting to think the problem lies elsewhere with Angular material

Comment: when I console log the ts code result, it prints out the result on every key press, its just not showing the <mat-error> on the first input focus

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I done something like this and it worked :(
`<div *ngFor="let error of errors_by_field['network']"><mat-error *ngIf="error">{{error.message}}</mat-error></div>`

I know material uses ErrorStateMatcher but that wont work with server side validation in my case